# Blur effect is not as expected

Tags: swift, uivisualeffectview

I'm trying to add blur effect to part of a **UIView**. What I expect from a blur is something like this:
[image]

But What I get is this:

[image]

This is code to blur:

```
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)) as UIVisualEffectView
visualEffectView.frame = blurFrame
myView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```

Is it possible to create blur effect like the first image?

Comment: If you test on another frame apart from `blurFrame` do you get your desired results?

Comment: @sweepez nah, it's same everywhere.